# How can i apply Unit Testing on my simple algorithm?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a maven project that draws Christmas tree. I need to implement Unit tests on it but i have no idea how to do it :/

I already set up , JUnit on my Maven project

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 10 - i; j++)
    System.out.print(" ");
   for (int k = 0; k < (2 * i + 1); k++)
    System.out.print("*");
   System.out.println();
  }
```

Comment: This is not a "code it for me" site. You need to provide a [mcve] for a specific problem for future.

Comment: I know but im still a student. Searched lots of files about TDD but still dont know how to apply testing on these simple algorithms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your class that draws Christmas tree looks more or less like that:

```
class ChristmasTreeDrafter {

    void draw() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10 - i; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int k = 0; k < (2 * i + 1); k++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

You can test it in that way:

```
public class ChristmasTreeDrafterTest {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDrawChristmasTree() {
        // given
        ChristmasTreeDrafter christmasTreeDrafter = new ChristmasTreeDrafter();

        // when
        christmasTreeDrafter.draw();

        // then
        Assert.assertEquals("          *\r\n" +
                "         ***\r\n" +
                "        *****\r\n" +
                "       *******\r\n", out.toString());
    }
}
```

In the `setup` method standard output stream is redirected to the `out` object and thanks to this you can verify its content in `then` block. Unfortunately Java has no multiline strings, so this code looks ugly. In order to improve readability you can extract this content to the file under `test/resources` (assuming default maven project structure).

Comment: This is really what i am looking for. Thank you . I will try to implement this on my code and see how it is going.

Comment: That's great! If it meets your expectations please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot man. Its my first time trying to do tests and this algorithm is a bit different. I couldnt manage to figure it out how can i test it  and im still learning java i couldnt think that i can use buffer.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level: the purpose of that code is to print a tree or triangle made of asterisks.  The test is simple, run the code and see of it generates the desired output.

Since the code is printing to System.out you will need to redirect System.out to a file or a string (see [this](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-write-console-output-to-text-file-in-java/)) then compare the generated output to the desired output to see of the code is operating properly.

Comment: First of all thanks for the idea. Now i will try to get an output of this tree and try to test in my test method to see if its equal to what i want or not.